# Parsing Priapea 31

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification, carmina-priapea

Intermediate here. I am having a hard time parsing this poem (Carmina Priapea 31).

> Donec proterva nil mei manu carpes,
> licebit ipsa sis pudicior Vesta.
> sin, haec mei te ventris arma laxabunt,
> exire ut ipse de tuo queas culo.

My problem is the last two lines. The translations I have seen seem to parse them roughly like this (using English word order)

> [haec arma mei ventris] laxabunt [te], ut queas exire de tuo culo ipse
> ...will loosen you such that you'll be able to exit from your own butt

Apart from the fact that this doesn't make a huge amount of sense, I am not sure about what *ipse* is supposed to be doing &mdas; if it's to agree with *culo* or even *tuo* then isn't it in the wrong form (some manuscripts have *ipsa* there, which doesn't help)?

I would like to parse them like this:

> [haec arma mei] laxabunt [te ventris], ut queas exire ipse de tuo culo
> ... will loosen your bowels such that you can pass them ...

That makes *ipse* stand for *venter*. But *te ventris* isn't really a construction I can find any support for.

Is there a definitively correct way to parse the lines as they stand, or will it always require emendation or something creative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ipse* is nominative; so the only thing it can be doing in the last line is modifying the subject of *queas*, which is the (unstated) pronoun *tu*.

The way you want to parse/translate the lines doesn't work, because the forms don't support it:

- If you're trying to make *haec arma mei* mean 'these weapons of mine,' that would be *haec arma mea*, using the adjective. You can't use *mei*, the genitive of the pronoun, for this.
- You're right to be uncomfortable taking *te* and *ventris* together. 'Your bowels' would need either a form of *tuus*, agreeing in gender, number, and case with *ventris*, or the dative form of the pronoun, *tibi*.
- Instead, *mei* and *ventris* go together, as noun+adjective. These genitive forms are dependent on *haec arma*, and *te* alone is the direct object of *laxabunt*.
- *Exire* can't mean 'pass *them*,' because 'them' would be a direct object, but *exire* is intransitive.

Long story short: The first translation that you give is correct. The god Priapus is threatening passers-by with rape if they steal anything that's under his protection.